# AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404 on vercel deployment

Tags: typescript, next.js, axios, prisma

I have an API route `app/api/posts/route.ts` that retrieves all posts from my database using Prisma ORM. On localhost, the database is my local PostgreSQL server, while on production, the database is hosted on `render.com`. I use axios on the `app/page.tsx` inside a function to get the response from my API route. Here is the code for that:

```js
import Card from "@/components/Card";
import axios from "axios";

const getPosts = async () => {
  const url =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
      ? "http://localhost:3000/api/posts"
      : "https://dropconnect.vercel.app/api/posts";
  const res = await axios.get(url);
  const data = await res.data;

  return data;
};

export default async function Home() {
  const posts = await getPosts();
  return (
    <div>
      {posts.length === 0 ? (
        <div>
          <p>No Posts have been made yet</p>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          {posts.map((post: any) => (
            <div key={post.id}>
              <Card
                id={post.id}
                title={post.title}
                content={post.content}
                comments={post.comments}
                noComments={post.noComments}
                noLikes={post.noLikes}
                name={post.author.name}
                image={post.author.image}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is my `/app/api/posts/route.ts` code:

```js
import { prisma } from "@/lib/database";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(req: Request) {
  const allPosts = await prisma.post.findMany({
    include: {
      comments: true,
      author: {
        select: {
          name: true,
          image: true,
        },
      },
    },
  });
  return NextResponse.json(allPosts);
}
```

And here is my `schema.prisma`:

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Post {
  id         String    @id @default(cuid())
  title      String
  content    String?
  noLikes    Int?      @default(0)
  noComments Int?      @default(0)
  author     User?     @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId   String?
  comments   Comment[]
}

model Comment {
  id       String  @id @default(cuid())
  content  String
  upvote   Int     @default(0)
  downvote Int     @default(0)
  author   User    @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId String
  post     Post?   @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id])
  postId   String?
}

model Account {
  id                String  @id @default(cuid())
  userId            String
  type              String
  provider          String
  providerAccountId String
  refresh_token     String? @db.Text
  access_token      String? @db.Text
  expires_at        Int?
  token_type        String?
  scope             String?
  id_token          String? @db.Text
  session_state     String?

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
}

model Session {
  id           String   @id @default(cuid())
  sessionToken String   @unique
  userId       String
  expires      DateTime
  user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}

model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
  comments      Comment[]
  posts         Post[]
}

model VerificationToken {
  identifier String
  token      String   @unique
  expires    DateTime

  @@unique([identifier, token])
}
```

On localhost it is working fine:
[image: all posts on api/posts route]

When I push my code to GitHub, vercel throws an AxiosError as follows:

```
...
[00:36:27.999] AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404
[00:36:27.999]     at settle (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/228.js:32264:16)
[00:36:27.999]     at BrotliDecompress.handleStreamEnd (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/228.js:33220:21)
[00:36:28.000]     at BrotliDecompress.emit (node:events:525:35)
[00:36:28.000]     at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
[00:36:28.000]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
[00:36:28.000]   code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',
[00:36:28.000]   config: {
[00:36:28.000]     transitional: {
[00:36:28.000]       silentJSONParsing: true,
[00:36:28.000]       forcedJSONParsing: true,
[00:36:28.000]       clarifyTimeoutError: false
[00:36:28.000]     },
[00:36:28.000]     adapter: [ 'xhr', 'http' ],
[00:36:28.001]     transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
[00:36:28.001]     transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
[00:36:28.002]     timeout: 0,
[00:36:28.002]     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
[00:36:28.002]     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
[00:36:28.002]     maxContentLength: -1,
[00:36:28.002]     maxBodyLength: -1,
[00:36:28.002]     env: { FormData: [Function], Blob: [class Blob] },
[00:36:28.002]     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
[00:36:28.002]     headers: AxiosHeaders {
[00:36:28.002]       Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
[00:36:28.002]       'User-Agent': 'axios/1.4.0',
[00:36:28.002]       'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
[00:36:28.002]     },
[00:36:28.002]     method: 'get',
[00:36:28.003]     url: 'https://dropconnect.vercel.app/api/posts',
[00:36:28.003]     data: undefined
[00:36:28.003]   },
[00:36:28.003]   request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
[00:36:28.004]     _events: [Object: null prototype] {
[00:36:28.004]       abort: [Function (anonymous)],
[00:36:28.004]       aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
[00:36:28.004]       connect: [Function (anonymous)],
[00:36:28.004]       error: [Function (anonymous)],
[00:36:28.005]       socket: [Function (anonymous)],
[00:36:28.005]       timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
[00:36:28.005]       finish: [Function: requestOnFinish]
[00:36:28.005]     },
[00:36:28.005]     _eventsCount: 7,
[00:36:28.005]     _maxListeners: undefined,
[00:36:28.005]     outputData: [],
[00:36:28.005]     outputSize: 0,
[00:36:28.005]     writable: true,
[00:36:28.005]     destroyed: true,
[00:36:28.005]     _last: true,
[00:36:28.005]     chunkedEncoding: false,
[00:36:28.005]     shouldKeepAlive: false,
[00:36:28.006]     maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
[00:36:28.006]     _defaultKeepAlive: true,
[00:36:28.006]     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
[00:36:28.006]     sendDate: false,
[00:36:28.006]     _removedConnection: false,
[00:36:28.006]     _removedContLen: false,
[00:36:28.006]     _removedTE: false,
[00:36:28.006]     strictContentLength: false,
[00:36:28.006]     _contentLength: 0,
[00:36:28.006]     _hasBody: true,
[00:36:28.006]     _trailer: '',
[00:36:28.006]     finished: true,
[00:36:28.007]     _headerSent: true,
[00:36:28.007]     _closed: true,
[00:36:28.007]     socket: TLSSocket {
[00:36:28.007]       _tlsOptions: [Object],
[00:36:28.007]       _secureEstablished: true,
[00:36:28.007]       _securePending: false,
[00:36:28.007]       _newSessionPending: false,
[00:36:28.007]       _controlReleased: true,
[00:36:28.007]       secureConnecting: false,
[00:36:28.007]       _SNICallback: null,
[00:36:28.007]       servername: 'dropconnect.vercel.app',
[00:36:28.007]       alpnProtocol: false,
[00:36:28.007]       authorized: true,
[00:36:28.007]       authorizationError: null,
[00:36:28.007]       encrypted: true,
[00:36:28.007]       _events: [Object: null prototype],
[00:36:28.007]       _eventsCount: 9,
[00:36:28.007]       connecting: false,
[00:36:28.008]       _hadError: false,
[00:36:28.008]       _parent: null,
[00:36:28.008]       _host: 'dropconnect.vercel.app',
[00:36:28.008]       _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
[00:36:28.008]       _readableState: [ReadableState],
[00:36:28.008]       _maxListeners: undefined,
[00:36:28.008]       _writableState: [WritableState],
[00:36:28.008]       allowHalfOpen: false,
[00:36:28.008]       _sockname: null,
[00:36:28.008]       _pendingData: null,
[00:36:28.008]       _pendingEncoding: '',
[00:36:28.008]       server: undefined,
[00:36:28.008]       _server: null,
[00:36:28.008]       ssl: null,
[00:36:28.008]       _requestCert: true,
[00:36:28.008]       _rejectUnauthorized: true,
[00:36:28.008]       parser: null,
[00:36:28.008]       _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
[00:36:28.009]       write: [Function: writeAfterFIN],
[00:36:28.009]       [Symbol(res)]: null,
[00:36:28.009]       [Symbol(verified)]: true,
[00:36:28.009]       [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
[00:36:28.009]       [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 2096,
[00:36:28.009]       [Symbol(kHandle)]: null,
[00:36:28.009]       [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
[00:36:28.009]       [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
[00:36:28.009]       [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
[00:36:28.009]       [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
[00:36:28.009]       [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
[00:36:28.009]       [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
[00:36:28.009]       [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
[00:36:28.009]       [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: true,
[00:36:28.009]       [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 60,
[00:36:28.009]       [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 1500,
[00:36:28.009]       [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 190,
[00:36:28.010]       [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object]
[00:36:28.010]     },
[00:36:28.010]     _header: 'GET /api/posts HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
[00:36:28.010]       'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
[00:36:28.010]       'User-Agent: axios/1.4.0\r\n' +
[00:36:28.010]       'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
[00:36:28.010]       'Host: dropconnect.vercel.app\r\n' +
[00:36:28.010]       'Connection: close\r\n' +
[00:36:28.011]       '\r\n',
[00:36:28.011]     _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
[00:36:28.011]     _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
[00:36:28.011]     agent: Agent {
[00:36:28.011]       _events: [Object: null prototype],
[00:36:28.011]       _eventsCount: 2,
[00:36:28.011]       _maxListeners: undefined,
[00:36:28.011]       defaultPort: 443,
[00:36:28.011]       protocol: 'https:',
[00:36:28.011]       options: [Object: null prototype],
[00:36:28.011]       requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
[00:36:28.011]       sockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
[00:36:28.011]       freeSockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
[00:36:28.011]       keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
[00:36:28.012]       keepAlive: false,
[00:36:28.012]       maxSockets: Infinity,
[00:36:28.012]       maxFreeSockets: 256,
[00:36:28.012]       scheduling: 'lifo',
[00:36:28.012]       maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
[00:36:28.012]       totalSocketCount: 0,
[00:36:28.012]       maxCachedSessions: 100,
[00:36:28.012]       _sessionCache: [Object],
[00:36:28.012]       [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
[00:36:28.012]     },
[00:36:28.012]     socketPath: undefined,
[00:36:28.012]     method: 'GET',
[00:36:28.012]     maxHeaderSize: undefined,
[00:36:28.012]     insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
[00:36:28.012]     joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
[00:36:28.012]     path: '/api/posts',
[00:36:28.013]     _ended: true,
[00:36:28.013]     res: IncomingMessage {
[00:36:28.013]       _readableState: [ReadableState],
[00:36:28.013]       _events: [Object: null prototype],
[00:36:28.014]       _eventsCount: 4,
[00:36:28.014]       _maxListeners: undefined,
[00:36:28.014]       socket: [TLSSocket],
[00:36:28.014]       httpVersionMajor: 1,
[00:36:28.015]       httpVersionMinor: 1,
[00:36:28.015]       httpVersion: '1.1',
[00:36:28.015]       complete: true,
[00:36:28.015]       rawHeaders: [Array],
[00:36:28.015]       rawTrailers: [],
[00:36:28.015]       joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
[00:36:28.015]       aborted: false,
[00:36:28.015]       upgrade: false,
[00:36:28.015]       url: '',
[00:36:28.015]       method: null,
[00:36:28.015]       statusCode: 404,
[00:36:28.015]       statusMessage: 'Not Found',
[00:36:28.015]       client: [TLSSocket],
[00:36:28.015]       _consuming: true,
[00:36:28.015]       _dumped: false,
[00:36:28.015]       req: [Circular *1],
[00:36:28.015]       responseUrl: 'https://dropconnect.vercel.app/api/posts',
[00:36:28.016]       redirects: [],
[00:36:28.016]       [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
[00:36:28.016]       [Symbol(kHeaders)]: [Object],
[00:36:28.016]       [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 30,
[00:36:28.016]       [Symbol(kTrailers)]: null,
[00:36:28.016]       [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0
[00:36:28.016]     },
[00:36:28.016]     aborted: false,
[00:36:28.016]     timeoutCb: null,
[00:36:28.016]     upgradeOrConnect: false,
[00:36:28.016]     parser: null,
[00:36:28.016]     maxHeadersCount: null,
[00:36:28.016]     reusedSocket: false,
[00:36:28.016]     host: 'dropconnect.vercel.app',
[00:36:28.016]     protocol: 'https:',
[00:36:28.016]     _redirectable: Writable {
[00:36:28.016]       _writableState: [WritableState],
[00:36:28.017]       _events: [Object: null prototype],
[00:36:28.017]       _eventsCount: 3,
[00:36:28.017]       _maxListeners: undefined,
[00:36:28.017]       _options: [Object],
[00:36:28.017]       _ended: true,
[00:36:28.017]       _ending: true,
[00:36:28.017]       _redirectCount: 0,
[00:36:28.017]       _redirects: [],
[00:36:28.017]       _requestBodyLength: 0,
[00:36:28.017]       _requestBodyBuffers: [],
[00:36:28.017]       _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
[00:36:28.017]       _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
[00:36:28.017]       _currentUrl: 'https://dropconnect.vercel.app/api/posts',
[00:36:28.017]       [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
[00:36:28.017]     },
[00:36:28.017]     [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
[00:36:28.017]     [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
[00:36:28.018]     [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
[00:36:28.018]     [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
[00:36:28.018]     [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
[00:36:28.018]       accept: [Array],
[00:36:28.018]       'user-agent': [Array],
[00:36:28.018]       'accept-encoding': [Array],
[00:36:28.018]       host: [Array]
[00:36:28.018]     },
[00:36:28.018]     [Symbol(errored)]: null,
[00:36:28.018]     [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
[00:36:28.018]   },
[00:36:28.018]   response: {
[00:36:28.018]     status: 404,
[00:36:28.018]     statusText: 'Not Found',
[00:36:28.018]     headers: AxiosHeaders {
[00:36:28.018]       'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
[00:36:28.018]       age: '424',
[00:36:28.019]       'cache-control': 'public, max-age=0, must-revalidate',
[00:36:28.019]       'content-disposition': 'inline; filename="404"',
[00:36:28.019]       'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
[00:36:28.019]       date: 'Tue, 25 Jul 2023 19:06:27 GMT',
[00:36:28.019]       etag: 'W/"38cd104fd7654933c13ecd14fe3bb23a"',
[00:36:28.019]       server: 'Vercel',
[00:36:28.019]       'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload',
[00:36:28.019]       'x-matched-path': '/404',
[00:36:28.019]       'x-vercel-cache': 'HIT',
[00:36:28.019]       'x-vercel-id': 'iad1::ld85f-1690311987976-439f46b5306b',
[00:36:28.019]       connection: 'close',
[00:36:28.019]       'transfer-encoding': 'chunked'
[00:36:28.019]     },
[00:36:28.019]     config: {
[00:36:28.019]       transitional: [Object],
[00:36:28.019]       adapter: [Array],
[00:36:28.019]       transformRequest: [Array],
[00:36:28.020]       transformResponse: [Array],
[00:36:28.020]       timeout: 0,
[00:36:28.020]       xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
[00:36:28.020]       xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
[00:36:28.020]       maxContentLength: -1,
[00:36:28.020]       maxBodyLength: -1,
[00:36:28.020]       env: [Object],
[00:36:28.020]       validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
[00:36:28.020]       headers: [AxiosHeaders],
[00:36:28.020]       method: 'get',
[00:36:28.020]       url: 'https://dropconnect.vercel.app/api/posts',
[00:36:28.020]       data: undefined
[00:36:28.020]     },
[00:36:28.020]     request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
[00:36:28.020]       _events: [Object: null prototype],
[00:36:28.020]       _eventsCount: 7,
[00:36:28.021]       _maxListeners: undefined,
[00:36:28.021]       outputData: [],
[00:36:28.021]       outputSize: 0,
[00:36:28.021]       writable: true,
[00:36:28.021]       destroyed: true,
[00:36:28.021]       _last: true,
[00:36:28.021]       chunkedEncoding: false,
[00:36:28.021]       shouldKeepAlive: false,
[00:36:28.021]       maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
[00:36:28.021]       _defaultKeepAlive: true,
[00:36:28.021]       useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
[00:36:28.021]       sendDate: false,
[00:36:28.021]       _removedConnection: false,
[00:36:28.021]       _removedContLen: false,
[00:36:28.021]       _removedTE: false,
[00:36:28.021]       strictContentLength: false,
[00:36:28.021]       _contentLength: 0,
[00:36:28.021]       _hasBody: true,
[00:36:28.022]       _trailer: '',
[00:36:28.022]       finished: true,
[00:36:28.022]       _headerSent: true,
[00:36:28.022]       _closed: true,
[00:36:28.022]       socket: [TLSSocket],
[00:36:28.022]       _header: 'GET /api/posts HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
[00:36:28.022]         'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
[00:36:28.022]         'User-Agent: axios/1.4.0\r\n' +
[00:36:28.022]         'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
[00:36:28.022]         'Host: dropconnect.vercel.app\r\n' +
[00:36:28.022]         'Connection: close\r\n' +
[00:36:28.022]         '\r\n',
[00:36:28.022]       _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
[00:36:28.022]       _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
[00:36:28.022]       agent: [Agent],
[00:36:28.022]       socketPath: undefined,
[00:36:28.023]       method: 'GET',
[00:36:28.023]       maxHeaderSize: undefined,
[00:36:28.023]       insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
[00:36:28.023]       joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
[00:36:28.023]       path: '/api/posts',
[00:36:28.023]       _ended: true,
[00:36:28.023]       res: [IncomingMessage],
[00:36:28.023]       aborted: false,
[00:36:28.023]       timeoutCb: null,
[00:36:28.023]       upgradeOrConnect: false,
[00:36:28.024]       parser: null,
[00:36:28.024]       maxHeadersCount: null,
[00:36:28.024]       reusedSocket: false,
[00:36:28.024]       host: 'dropconnect.vercel.app',
[00:36:28.024]       protocol: 'https:',
[00:36:28.024]       _redirectable: [Writable],
[00:36:28.024]       [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
[00:36:28.024]       [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
[00:36:28.024]       [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
[00:36:28.024]       [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
[00:36:28.024]       [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
[00:36:28.024]       [Symbol(errored)]: null,
[00:36:28.024]       [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
[00:36:28.024]     },
[00:36:28.024]     data: '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charSet="utf-8"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/><title>404: This page could not be found</title><meta name="next-head-count" content="3"/><noscript data-n-css=""></noscript><script defer="" nomodule="" src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills-78c92fac7aa8fdd8.js"></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack-92754179cd20598c.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/framework-8883d1e9be70c3da.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/main-a12802a46038f17d.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-52924524f99094ab.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/_error-c92d5c4bb2b49926.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/qfvK-D30q5wNwyttqQ8cC/_buildManifest.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/qfvK-D30q5wNwyttqQ8cC/_ssgManifest.js" defer=""></script></head><body><div id="__next"><div style="font-family:system-ui,&quot;Segoe UI&quot;,Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif,&quot;Apple Color Emoji&quot;,&quot;Segoe UI Emoji&quot;;height:100vh;text-align:center;display:flex;flex-direction:column;align-items:center;justify-content:center"><div style="line-height:48px"><style>body{color:#000;background:#fff;margin:0}.next-error-h1{border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3)}@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark){body{color:#fff;background:#000}.next-error-h1{border-right:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3)}}</style><h1 class="next-error-h1" style="display:inline-block;margin:0 20px 0 0;padding-right:23px;font-size:24px;font-weight:500;vertical-align:top">404</h1><div style="display:inline-block"><h2 style="font-size:14px;font-weight:400;line-height:28px">This page could not be found<!-- -->.</h2></div></div></div></div><script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json">{"props":{"pageProps":{"statusCode":404}},"page":"/_error","query":{},"buildId":"qfvK-D30q5wNwyttqQ8cC","nextExport":true,"isFallback":false,"gip":true,"scriptLoader":[]}</script></body></html>'
[00:36:28.024]   }
[00:36:28.025] }
[00:36:28.026] 
[00:36:28.026] Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
[00:36:28.026] AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404
[00:36:28.026]     at settle (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/228.js:32264:16)
[00:36:28.026]     at BrotliDecompress.handleStreamEnd (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/228.js:33220:21)
[00:36:28.026]     at BrotliDecompress.emit (node:events:525:35)
[00:36:28.026]     at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
[00:36:28.026]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
[00:36:28.461] prisma:query SELECT "public"."Post"."id", "public"."Post"."title", "public"."Post"."content", "public"."Post"."noLikes", "public"."Post"."noComments", "public"."Post"."authorId" FROM "public"."Post" WHERE 1=1 OFFSET $1
[00:36:28.468] - info Generating static pages (7/7)
[00:36:28.473] 
[00:36:28.473] > Export encountered errors on following paths:
[00:36:28.473]  /page: /
[00:36:28.525] Error: Command "npx prisma generate && next build" exited with 1
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This error occur because `localhost` isn't avaiable on vercel and you're also you a `custom domain` which is also undefined because domain is connect in the last stage of deployment but your code is `SSG` and also a `server component`.

You need to directly use this code in your server component...

```
const allPosts = await prisma.post.findMany({
    include: {
      comments: true,
      author: {
        select: {
          name: true,
          image: true,
        },
      },
    }
})
```

Comment: if you see the `app/page.tsx` file, i have configured the URL such that on localhost and vercel it uses different URLs accordingly, so the issue shouldn't rise right?

Comment: We can do what you have suggested as well. But if someone insists on using the API route, they can check the other solution down here. Thanks for your input mate

Comment: @GNVageesh first understand how nextjs works. The way you try to implement url is not working in any ways . When the build progress is working in vercel then vercel fetch the data from api route and localhost is not available and your custom domain also isn't available because custom domain are applied after the build process then how you can fetch the data from database using API route. My answer is 100% true and I also doing in my own projects and you have server component that's my it's completely secure

Answer (score -1):

So here is what I did to solve this.

I removed everything from `app/page.tsx` and returned a simple component with a h1 tag. After that, I pushed the code, and that deployed on Vercel without any errors. Later, I wrote the same code into `app/page.tsx` that I shared in the question and pushed it to GitHub. The deployment was without any issues.

My guess is that Vercel and Next were checking for the code and tried the Axios GET request, which failed since the `/app/api/posts/route.tsx` file was not yet created by the `npm build` command. By doing what I did, in the first deployment, the route was created, and then in the second deployment, the API route was there hence Axios didn't throw any error.

Comment: Vercel don't have any localhost and custom domain in build process

Comment: I get it. The API route wasn't built before, hence this error was coming. So I made a dummy page component first, with this there were no errors, and then the second time I did what I was doing, calling using Axios, and it worked